# sort and transfer tables from on workbook to another

Tags: sorting, transfer

I am trying to sort all cells with "approve" word inside it then once done I want to transfer a row with "approve cells to another workbook and clear other cells

i tried a code that can successfully sort all approve items and transfer it to another workbook but fail